# image gallery with next and previous button css or js only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was able to successfully create an image gallery from [this](http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp7y) tutorial.

Now I am having problems with the images I want to display in my gallery. I want to display as much image as possible and I want to show only 3 or 5 images in the thumbnail then the user can keep on pressing next or previous as they want, but when I tried to put images on they all show up.

I tried putting `padding`, `margin` or `overflow` but unfortunately I wasn't able to get the result I want.

My html code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>sample gallery</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        .active {
            border: 1px solid #ff0000;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(function () {
            (function () {
                $("#thumbs").find(".thumb:first").addClass("active");
                $("#large").find(".bigthumb:first").addClass("active");

                var getIndex = $("#thumbs").find(".active").index();

                $(".controls").each(function () {
                    console.log($(this).find(".nextgallery"));
                    $(this).find(".nextgallery").click(function () {
                        alert(".nextgallery");
                        getIndex = $("#thumbs").find(".active").index();
                        getIndex += 1;
                        if (getIndex > ($("#thumbs").find(".thumb").length - 1)) {
                            getIndex = 0;
                        }
                        setActiveImage(getIndex);
                    });
                    $(this).find(".prevgallery").click(function () {
                        alert(".prevgallery");
                        getIndex -= 1;
                        if (getIndex < 0) {
                            getIndex = $("#thumbs").find(".thumb").length - 1;
                        }
                        setActiveImage(getIndex); //Set/Show Active Image
                    });
                });

            })();

            function setActiveImage(index) {
                if (typeof (index) == "undefined" || index == "" || index == null) index = 0;

                $("#thumbs").find(".thumb").removeClass("active");
                $("#thumbs").find(".thumb:eq(" + index + ")").addClass("active");
                $("#large").find(".bigthumb").removeClass("active");
                $("#large").find(".bigthumb:eq(" + index + ")").addClass("active");
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="panel">
        <div class="controls">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="" style="height: 50px; width: 50px;" class="prevgallery">
            <span>Thumbnail Navigation 
            </span>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="" style="height: 50px; width: 50px;" class="nextgallery">
        </div>
        <div id="thumbs">
            <div class="thumb active">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="" width="100" height="80">
            </div>
            <div class="thumb">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="" width="100" height="80">
            </div>
            <div class="thumb">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="" width="100" height="80">
            </div>
            <div class="thumb">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="" width="100" height="80">
            </div>
            <div class="thumb">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="" width="100" height="80">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="controls" align="center" width="400px">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="" style="height: 50px; width: 50px;" class="prevgallery">
            <span>Large Image Navigation 
            </span>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="" style="height: 50px; width: 50px;" class="nextgallery">
        </div>
        <div id="large">
            <div class="bigthumb active">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="bigthumb">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="bigthumb">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="bigthumb">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="bigthumb">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

UPDATE:

I want the gallery of image like the one in yahoo..
[image]
UPDATE:
problem how to make other image hidden if the images are more than 5..

Comment: Instead of assuming we know what "the one in yahoo" looks like, how about a link/screenshot? Also, sample code and an example of what _you_ have tried helps us to understand what the problem is. You've said you've tried to modify that example. How? Why didn't it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasnt able to find the perfect answer for this but what i did is just put display:table-cell; and just figure the width and height as for the hidden images im still working to figure it out

Answer (score 0):

if i able to view your code , i would have suggest you few changes to get that kind of o/p.

Till now you can refer these links:
http://rip747.github.io/Yahoo-style-news-slider-for-jQuery/
http://www.tn3gallery.com/

Comment: something like that what is called and how to implement it any tutorial on that one?

Comment: i cant give the perfect answer as i dot no wts the structure of your code, but its just the 'js' and 'html' issue with little bit 'css' will able to fix it